# Secure connection between REST server and mongoDB (in JAVA)

Tags: mongodb, authentication, ssl, mongodb-java

I have a Rest server and looking for a way to secure the connection between Rest server(Spring) and mongoDB ()
my code:

```js
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/multimedia")
public class collectionController {

  @Autowired
  private Repository repository;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value= "createMultimedia")
  public Map<String, String> createMultimedia(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> Url){

        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("MyDataBase1"); 
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("MyDBCollection1");  
        //... do something

      return resp;
  }
```

is there any way or example to secure this data transmittion for example https or other encryotion . if yes , please let me know how.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you can configure the server for [SSL](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/) as can the client connect using [this as well](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#uri.ssl). Notably your current connection is on localhost, so it's not going to presently matter that much. But with a remote host then it's a valid option.

Comment: thank you so much , its is on localhost for now and will replace with a remote server. do you have any code example ? I appreciated if you answer me with a code example. thank you

Comment: ant help and example is appreciated